# Execution of empty space in calculator crashes android

Tags: java, android

I am beginner in Android.
I made a calculator. It works fine when there is a value in the boxes but if they're empty it crashes.
I have tried many things

the first loop for divide has the problem.
I haven't implemented it on other arithmetic operations,just divide.

```
    package com.example.bilal.aaa;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText t,t2;
    TextView t3;
    Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b6;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        t2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
        t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edittext3);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                create(v);
            }
        });


        Button b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                create(v);
            }
        });

        Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                create(v);
            }
        });

        Button b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                create(v);
            }
        });

        try{

            b1.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

            b2.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

            b3.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

            b4.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

            b6.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener)this);



        }

        catch(Exception e){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Add the Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }






    }

    String a,b;
    Double A1,B1;
    Double result;
int AA1,BB1;


    public void create(View v) {



        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button1:
                a = t.getText().toString();
                b=t2.getText().toString();
                A1=Double.parseDouble(a);
                B1=Double.parseDouble(b);



                    if (a.equals(null)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter First Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    create(v);
                    } else if (b.equals(null)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Second Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        create(v);
                    } else if (A1.equals(null)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter First Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        create(v);
                    } else if (B1.equals(null)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Second Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        create(v);
                    }   else
                        {
                            result=A1/B1;
                      answer(v);
                        }







//                Log.e("EXCEPTION", a);
//                Log.e("EXCEPTION",b);}
//                else{
//
//
//                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "value"+A1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "value"+B1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        result=A1/B1;
//                        answer(v);
//                    Log.e("EXCEPTION","A is Null");
//                }

//                if(a.equals(null)){
//                    Log.e("EXCEPTION",a);
//                    Log.e("EXCEPTION",b);
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter First Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    create(v);
//
//
//                }
//                    else{
//                    if(b.equals(null)){
//                        Log.e("EXCEPTION","A is Null");
//                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Second Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        create(v);
//
//                    }
//                    else {
////                        A1=Double.parseDouble(a);
////                        B1=Double.parseDouble(b);
//
//                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "value"+A1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "value"+B1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        result=A1/B1;
//                        answer(v);
//
//                    }
//
//            }


                break;

            case R.id.button2:
                a = t.getText().toString();
                b=t2.getText().toString();
                A1=Double.parseDouble(a);

                B1=Double.parseDouble(b);
                if(a!=null){
                    if(b!=null){

                        result=A1*B1;
                        answer(v);





                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Second Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter First Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter First Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }




                break;
            case R.id.button3:

                a = t.getText().toString();
                b=t2.getText().toString();
                A1=Double.parseDouble(a);
                B1=Double.parseDouble(b);

                if(A1 != 0){
                    if(B1 != 0){
                        result=A1+B1;
                        answer(v);


                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Second Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
                else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter First Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
                break;
            case R.id.button4:

                a = t.getText().toString();
                b=t2.getText().toString();
                A1=Double.parseDouble(a);
                B1=Double.parseDouble(b);

                if(A1 != 0){
                    if(B1 != 0){
                        result=A1-B1;
                        answer(v);


                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Second Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
                else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter First Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
                break;

            default:  Toast.makeText(this, "INVALID OPTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;


        }
    }


    public void clear(View v)
    {

        t.setText("");
        t2.setText("");

    }

    public void answer(View v)
    {

        String tmpstring = Double.toString(result);

        t3.setText(tmpstring);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }






    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

message from LOGCAT

```
05-12 15:01:20.709    5624-5624/com.example.bilal.aaa D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-12 15:01:20.869    5624-5624/com.example.bilal.aaa E/dalvikvm﹕ dvmResumeGc(0xf126, 0) called (f=0x1)
05-12 15:01:31.504    5624-5624/com.example.bilal.aaa D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-12 15:01:31.504    5624-5624/com.example.bilal.aaa W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x420b5c08)
05-12 15:01:31.514    5624-5624/com.example.bilal.aaa E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.bilal.aaa, PID: 5624
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
at com.example.bilal.aaa.MainActivity.create(MainActivity.java:102)
at com.example.bilal.aaa.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 15:01:57.889    5733-5733/com.example.bilal.aaa E/dalvikvm﹕ dvmPauseGc(AppLaunch) called - cookie=0x835c (f=0x1)
```

Comment: a space is not a valid numerical value and can not be parsed to a double. This is expected behaviour. What did you want to get: "" + 5 = 8 ?

Comment: Thats easy, if there is no text, you can't parse double from it, you should use some condition like if(!String.isEmpty())

Comment: This is the line in which error  occures

Comment: A1=Double.parseDouble(a);
  B1=Double.parseDouble(b);

Comment: Bilal, we know. we also have already explained what the cause is.

Comment: @NikMyers  same problem with your solution.if u can give more detailed if statment,that  would help

Comment: @Stultuske i understood what the problem is.but how do i solve it

Comment: that has also been said already. check for an empty String before trying to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    case R.id.button1:
        a = t.getText().toString();
        b=t2.getText().toString();
        A1=Double.parseDouble(a);
        B1=Double.parseDouble(b);
```

This part you should check your a and b for String.isEmpty(), and your t2 if it's not null:

```
 case R.id.button1:
if(t != null && !t.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
     a = t.getText().toString();
     A1=Double.parseDouble(a);
}

if(t2 != null && !t2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
     b = t2.getText().toString();
     B1=Double.parseDouble(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple, for example, initialize the variables and check if it is null BEFORE parse the string to number.:

```
String a,b;
Double A1=0
Double B1=0;
Double result=0;

    a = t.getText().toString();
    b=t2.getText().toString();

    if(a!=null && !a.equals("")){
    A1=Double.parseDouble(a);
    }else{
      //make Your Toast
    }

    if(b!=null && !b.equals("")){
    B1=Double.parseDouble(b);
    }else{
         //make Your Toast
     }
```

...and so on....

### EDIT

And beware of wrong input. If You only wants to have a numeric input, You have to set the inputType to Your editText fields inside Your layout xml:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

API Reference for inputType: [InputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

And, if You want to check if a String is null, don´t use equals. For a String it must be:

```
if(a==null) or if(a!=null)
```

Use euqals only to compare strings.

Comment: but if a would be "", it will pass your condition and app will crash

Comment: not if OP has set the inputType correct. I presume if OP wants parse numbers, he knows it...

Comment: but i don't think that way, see the error __java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""__ , he doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.
@Nik Myers solution worked,Thanks

case R.id.button1:

```
            if(t != null && !t.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                if (t2 != null && !t2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    b = t2.getText().toString();
                    B1 = Double.parseDouble(b);
                    a = t.getText().toString();
                    A1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
                    result = A1 / B1;
                    answer(v);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter First Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Second Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```